# OnClick event - Run php script over ajax in Mozilla

Tags: php, ajax, onclick, mozilla

I solved one problem that occurred only in one of the updates from Mozilla. I have a program in jQuery, which records click on element div#region. Click to run php script that clicks saved in the database. But if this div link  click  so, although php script recording clicks using $.get calls, but does not start. This is how it behaves just in Mozilla, in any other browser I have not seen such behavior. If you can look in Firebug to call php script.

Is it standard behavior for safety, optimization or for something else? Or is this a Mozilla bug or is it poorly written code??

HTML:

```
<div id="region">
<p>nejaky text</p>
<a href="http://www.test.cz" target="_blank">click</a>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#region").click(function(){
$.get('/ajax/add_click.php?id=5');
});
});
});
```

I could not find a solution on the internet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change like this

```
<div id="region">
   <p>nejaky text</p>
   <a href="http://www.test.cz" target="_blank">click</a>
</div>
```

and your jquery will be

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#region").click(function(e){
       e.preventDefault();         //Add preventDefault here
       window.open($(this + 'a').attr('href'));
       $.get('/ajax/add_click.php?id=5');
    });
});
```

Comment: I need to call the script add_click.php and parallel opened the site  www.test.cz in new panel in Mozilla. If I add a.preventDefault(), then page www.test.cz not open.

Comment: I need to record clicks on the whole area. Not only on the links.

Comment: Yes tried it, but it will not work as I expect. See previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Did you test on your local file system perhaps? When I try your code local I see nothing happening as well, but as on a remote server it does work for me.

Comment: Yes. I test on my localhost. After clicking on the area div#region to open a new page www.test.cz. Its ok. In firebug I see that the script called add_click.php, but on the timeline in Firebug I see that the script does not start add_click. Why is this so?

Comment: in each browser it works, just not in mozilla. It stopped working after one of the upgrade mozilla.

Comment: With local filesystem I mean that you access a file through for example 'file:///C:/filename.php', but I assume you just used 'localhost/filename.php. Maybe some add-on is causing a conflict. But did you check if you can get any data from the server by using a callback function?

Comment: yes, to the script access is enabled, run from the same directory as the html file. Php script not return. Script do not return any data.

Comment: you're right, it looks that it blocks some addon. thanks a lot

Comment: Well, if it happened after an upgrade it does sound like a Mozilla bug or some add-on conflict (you could try disabling them) or a firewall problem (you could try to disable that too:) ). Otherwise I wouldn't have a clue. Perhaps you can try $.ajax instead though, but that sounds unlikely.